# Showing the biggest combination of numbers between a certain number range

Tags: c

the goal of the code is to show the number that if we combine its numebrs it will be the biggest between our range, so if the numbers are 1050 - 950 the number that will show will be 999 because its numbers combined are the biggest between that group of numbers.

For some reason when I run the program and enter the two first numbers (right and left) it shows nothing, also it doesn't show the lines it's always showing when the code is done working.

```
int main()
{
    int right, left, units, tens, hundreds, thousands, save, save1 = 0, num;

    printf("Enter big number\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &right);
    
    printf("Enter small number\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &left);

    
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
    {
        num = i;
    
        units = num % 10;
        num = num - units;
        tens = num %100/10;
        num = num - tens;
        hundreds = num % 1000 /100;
        num = num - hundreds;
        thousands = num % 10000/1000;

        save = units + tens + hundreds + thousands;

        if (save > save1)
        {
            save1 = save;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", save1);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `left < i < right` is not a thing. It compiles, but it does something you don't want. (one of the `<` evaluates to 0/1 bool which is then compared to the remaining number). You probably wanted `i<right` as the condition.

Comment: Smart idea, I changed it as you said but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I enter the two numbers and it's showing nothing, not even finishing the code.

Comment: Next stop: you are altering the loop variable `i` inside the loop. Are you absolutely sure you want to do that? If yes, see preceding question.

Comment: Use a debugger to trace how the variables change, or just do it in your head. For example, for the number 1234, what are al the intermediate variables?

Comment: You really shouldn't change the loop variable.  And the whole way you are getting the digits is wrong.  Even if you copy the value of i to a variable that you can modify you are not saving individual digits.  You can fix it like this: https://ideone.com/WPbtBZ but then you are just doing extra for no reason - if you want to save digits then do it this way: https://ideone.com/fO7Fn8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some changes what you need on your code in order to do what you expect.

**First** is about the condition on your loop, but i see you already edited that.

**Second**, you can't change your iterator on the math you are doing every loop and expect to work, so i suggest to use an auxiliary variable.

**Third**, you need to divide teens per 10 , hundreds per 100 and thousands per 1000 in order to achieve the result you want.

**Last but not least** you are saving the sum but not the number so when actual sum is bigger than the previous one you should save the number too.

Try to **do that modifications by yourself before you see the code** i will display here.

This is my resolution to your problem.

**Output:**

```
Enter big number
1050
Enter small number
950
999
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int right, left, units, tens, hundreds, thousands, save, save1 = 0, bigSum = 0, aux;

    printf("Enter big number\n");
    scanf("%d", &right);
    
    printf("Enter small number\n");
    scanf("%d", &left);

    
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
    {

        aux = i;

        units = i % 10;
        aux = aux - units;
        tens = aux %100;
        aux = aux - tens;
        hundreds = aux % 1000;
        aux = aux - hundreds;
        thousands = aux % 10000;

        tens /= 10;
        hundreds /= 100;
        thousands /= 1000;

        save = units + tens + hundreds + thousands;

        if (save > save1)
        {
            save1 = save;
            bigSum = units + tens * 10 + hundreds * 100 + thousands * 1000;
            //or bigSum = i;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", bigSum);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i recommend you to read and try to understand the code that @nielsen put in his answer , it's more clean and compact and work for bigger  numbers too

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the `i` value in the for loop and essentially creating an infinite loop make a copy of `i` and use that instead in your loop.

```
for (int i = left; i <= right; i++)
    {
        int n = i;

        units = n % 10;
        n = n - units;
        tens = n % 100;
        n = n - tens;
        hundreds = n % 1000;
        n = n - hundreds;
        thousands = n % 10000;

        save = units + tens + hundreds + thousands;

        if (save > save1)
        {
            save1 = save;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code. A possibly incomplete list is:

- The extraction of digits is incorrect
- The code saves only the maximal sum of digits, not the number resulting in that sum
- The code allows for negative numbers, but they are not handled and the purpose does not seem to allow negative numbers
- The code in the loop changes the iteration variable `i` causing the loop to malfunction
- Digits above thousands (ten-thousands etc.) are not handled

A fixed version could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned right, left, n, nMaxSum = 0, sum, maxSum = 0;

    printf("Enter big number\n");
    scanf_s("%u", &right);
    
    printf("Enter small number\n");
    scanf_s("%u", &left);

    
    for (unsigned i = left; i < right; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        n = i;
        while(n != 0)
        {
            sum += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
    
        if (sum > maxSum)
        {
            maxSum = sum;
            nMaxSum = i;
        }
    }

    printf("%u (sum: %u)\n", nMaxSum, maxSum);


    return 0;
}
```