# sum of all the digit of a number using while-loop in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve a problem (as the title already state). I've actually learned that I can do it with *modulo operator* (%). But the first code that I wrote is using the *while-loop*, so I'm trying to finish the code.

This is the code

```
int main()
{
 char arr[1000000];
 int i = 0;
 int sum = 0;

    printf("type the number = ");
    scanf("%s", arr);

    while(arr[i] != '\0'){
        sum = arr[i] + sum;
        i++;
}

printf("the total number is = %d", sum);
```

so the problem is it's actually printing out some huge amount of number.. I guess it's because of the array is in **char**, can someone help me how do I changed the value into **int** ?

Comment: subtract '0' from each char before adding it to the sum. And actually you can't do it with % if you plan to support 1000000 digit numbers.

Comment: can I ask why it must be substract with '0' ? but thankyou before, it worked !

Comment: The digits are ASCII characters and 0 is '0' or 48. So you need to scale them down to integer values. See the ASCII chart for more info.

Comment: `arr[i]` is the ASCII value of the character (for example, '0' is 48). You can subtract 48 (or '0') from each character value, exploiting the fact that the numbers from 0 to 9 are next to each other in the ASCII table. Or you can add (arr[i]&0xF), since the numbers are arranged in such a way that their least significant nibble equals their decimal value (so, 0 is 0x30, 7 is 0x37 and 9 is 0x39 so on - the trick is used in BCD coding to squeeze *two* digits in a single byte).

Comment: what are the requirements, are you allowed to keep the input as a string, or do you need to convert it to an `int` or similar first? And you're expecting inputs a million digits long? Goodness. Careful, even that buffer can be overflowed.

Comment: Don't subtract 48 but `'0'`. It doesn't matter what value the character `'0'` has. The digit characters `'0'` to `'9'` are guaranteed to be consecutively encoded. So `'0' - '0'` is integer `0`, and `'1' - '0'` is `1`, etc to `'9' - '0'` is `9`.

Comment: You may also have a look here (shows how to calculate the sum of digits using an integer data type): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343372/showing-the-biggest-combination-of-numbers-between-a-certain-number-range/69344093#69344093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to substract from the digit code the code of `'0'`.

Here you have the both versions (I have added some logic to accept the numbers with `+` & `-` at there beginning):

```
int sumdigitsStr(const char *num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int first = 1;
    while(*num)
    {
        if(isdigit(*num)) {sum += *num - '0'; first = 0;}
        else 
        if(first && (*num == '-' || *num == '+'))
        {
            first = 0;
            num++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        { 
            sum = -1; break;
        } //error string contains non digits
        num++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumdigits(long long num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    do
    {
        sum += abs((int)(num % 10));
    }while((num = num / 10));
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int d, sum = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        d = n % 10;
        sum = sum + d;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    printf("sum of digits is : %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```